# Weighted sampling giving biased results

Tags: r, sampling, weighted, probability-distribution

I would like to perform a weighted sampling of rows from a dataframe with R, using a probability distribution calculated from one of the groups.

These are the variables in my dataframe:

`colnames(table) <- c('PF', 'verticality', 'nr.genomes', 'mean.branch', 'tot.branch','nr.species', 'replicon')`

Now, I calculated the probability distribution for the variable 'nr.genomes' from one of the groups in variable 'replicon':

```
freq <- table(table$nr.genomes[(table$replicon=='LPP')])
prob <- as.data.frame(prop.table(freq))
colnames(prob) <- c('nr.genomes', 'prob')
```

Then, I merged the prob and table dataframes so that each row has a probability to be sampled as previously defined and subtract the 'CHR' group, as this is the subset where I want to do the sampling

```
table.probs = merge(x = table, y = prob, by = "nr.genomes")
table.chr <- table.probs[(table.probs$replicon=='CHR'),]
```

Then, I do rounds of sampling and save all results in df.final dataframe:

```
for(i in 1:100) {
  sampled_rows <- sample(1:NROW(table.chr), size = 1097, prob = table.chr$prob)
  sampled_df <- table.chr[sampled_rows, ]
  run <- rep(as.character(i), 1097)
  df <- cbind(run, sampled_df)
  df.final <- rbind(df.final, df)
}
```

These are the final distributions:

[image]

The green line belongs to the group for which the probability distribution was calculated and the grey ones to the samples. So, as you can see, the weighted samples are clearly biased.

Can you identify any mistakes in the approach or have any ideas what may be causing the bias?

thank you!

Comment: At a glance, I can see that you merge two data.frames to create `df` and then not only you do not use `df` in the loop but you rewrite it every time through it. And backtracking, you compute the probabilities from `table.clean`, with `replicon == 'LPP'` but subset a different data.frame also named `df` keeping the group `replicon=='CHR'`. Your data naming is at best messy. *Maybe this is not where the error comes from but it definitely makes finding the error more difficult.*

Comment: I tried to show what I thought would be more relevant as I am quite confident that there is no problem related to the dataframes. Anyway, I tried to edit the post with more meaningful names and hope this helps.